# How to display a local pdf file in a panel in sencha touch +phonegap app?

Tags: android, pdf, cordova, sencha-touch-2

I am working in a *sencha touch+phonegap* app where I need to display a local PDF file inside a panel but I am not able to do so. Below are the few things I have tried:-

1. Used PDF viewer plugin provided by *mozilla* like

   `xtype: 'panel',`

   `centered: true,`

   `html: '< embed type:"application/pdf width:"300px" height: "500px" src="assets/myfile.pdf"`

   It works fine in browser but displays a white screen in mobile. I have also tried changing the relative path of source file but no effect.
2. Used a PDF viewer panel provided by *sencha* [here](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?239388-A-PDF-Viewer-Panel-No-Browser-Plugin-required-pure-JavaScript)
   This works fine with PDFs from web server(if I give a external URL address it works) but if I give the path of a local file then it displays `"Loading pdf, please wait"` infinitely.

Please Help...!!!

Answer (score 0):

Is your the asset in your app.json file? Make sure app.json resources array has a line for the assets directory so that the packager includes it in the build.